# do node.js require method use heap memory?

Tags: node.js, memory, module

1.
I'm just curious about how do require method use memory.
I think it might use heap memory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhvN.png)

am i right?

2. how can i check value address(memory address)

Comment: Note that for an interpreted language like Javascript or Ruby or Python or PHP the interpreter's stack is typically implemented in heap memory. So in a sense everything is in heap. Specifically for languages with closures the distinction between stack and heap does not make sense because for such a language the call "stack" (or more correctly the activation record) cannot be implemented as a stack but must be implemented as a linked list or map instead because of how closures work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just curious about how do require method use memory.

Yes, `require()` uses memory.  It loads code into memory and then any code in that module that runs during initialization may create Javascript objects that also use memory.

> how can i check value address(memory address)

Javascript does not expose memory addresses for things in the heap (that is internal to the implementation).

You can do heap snapshots in node.js that will show you what is in the heap, but that does not show addresses.

---

These questions are a bit out in left field which makes me think you're confused about how you might go about solving a particular problem.  If you shared the actual problem you're trying to solve, we could probably help you better.